# How to install Python 3 in RHEL in such a way that it won't mess up the current Python 2 installation?

Tags: linux, installation, python, python3

I have an EC2 instance which is running Python 2.x. I want to install python 3.x but I do not know if Python 2 is currently being used by anything. My questions are:

1. How do I install Python 3 in such a way that it does not mess with the existing Python 2 setup?
2. Can I install it separately, such as the variable for it is Python3 instead of Python?

Comment: If you only need python3 for a specific program you can "install" it into your user home or to `/opt`. For scripts you want to start with python3 start them via `<path-to-python3>/python3 script.py` or modify the shebang entry in the script's first line to point to your python3 installation.

Comment: Thanks. How do I 'install' it? Just yum install python3?

Comment: I was talking about downloading from the Python home page and unzipping it. I was assuming that you were asking because Python3 is not available through your package manager.

Comment: It is available, but I am afraid to install it just in case if it messed up the processes that are currently being run with python2.

Comment: But this is an EC2 instance - you should be able to create a snapshot install Python3 and if it does not work go back to the snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

you can install python3 using dnf or yum

```
yum install python3
```

and python 3 will be reachable by  python3
and python 2 will be available by  python